# Geometric or topological results from group theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, big-list, geometric-group-theory

Do you know interesting examples of purely geometric or topological results which can be proved using group theory? To make precise what I have in mind, let us consider the two following examples:

> There does not exist any Riemannian metric on the torus whose sectional curvature is $<0$.

This is a consequence of Milnor's article *A note on curvature and fundamental group*, where he proves that the fundamental group of a negatively-curved Riemannian manifold has exponential growth. On the other hand, the fundamental group of the torus, namely $\mathbb{Z}^2$, has quadratic growth.

> Any compact Riemannian manifold whose sectional curvature is $\equiv 0$ has a torus as a finite cover.

This is a consequence of Bieberbach theorem.

More recently, showing that quasiconvex subgroups of hyperbolic cubulable groups are separable was the key point in the proof of the virtual Haken's conjecture. However, this is more technical.

Comment: Do, e.g., results concerning word-hyperbolic groups count, or are they disqualified on grounds that the spaces involved are "synthesized" by the groups themselves?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I would call Milnor's theorem a "result proved by group theory". I think the proof is pure geometry.

Comment: @ThiKu: The same is actually true for Bieberbach's theorem. It also doesn't really use group theory.

Comment: I think the virtual Haken and virtually Fibering conjectures are good examples where group theory plays a key role although there are other techniques as well.

Comment: I'm not convinced that any such results are proved *purely* using group theory: certainly none of the examples given so far qualify. The fact of the matter is that modern group theory is inextricably intertwined with geometry.  If the question is just 'list theorems in geometric and topological group theory', then it's far too broad

Comment: Let us replace "proved using group theory" with "proved using surprisingly group theory". I mean a statement which seems not to be connected to group theory at first glance, but nevertheless which can be proved by introducing groups in the good place. Of course, we do not allow the arguments which turn out to be completely elementary nowadays: for instance, the fundamental group as a tool to distinguish spaces or knots.

Comment: @Seiros, I'm still puzzled by what you mean by 'group theory'.  For instance, Benjamin Steinberg mentioned the Virtual Haken conjecture, and indeed, the theorem 'any cubulable hyperbolic group is a quasiconvex subgroup of a right-angled Artin group' sounds a lot like group theory.  On the other hand, the theorem 'any npc cube complex with hyperbolic fundamental group is virtually special' sounds less like group theory, and indeed Agol's proof (and Wise's previous work) is phrased more in the language of cube complexes.  So do these qualify or not?

Comment: As you said, now group theory is intertwined with geometry. I am not looking for proofs which use only group theory, but rather proofs where the introduction of a notion of group theory is fundamental, and a fortiori unexpected. For the example of the Virtual Haken conjecture, the key point is to prove the separability of some subgroups in the fundamental group, so for me this is a good example.

Comment: For the proof of Milnor's theorem, I think one can phrase it without mentioning groups: any two metrics on a compact surface are quasi-isometric, so are their lifts to the universal covering space. So the volume growth of metric balls has to be of the same type (exponential or polynomial) in both cases. So one can not have both, a flat metric and a negatively curved one. The important concept here is that of quasi-isometry, while the fundamental group and the Milnor-Svarc lemma are actually not necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Determining whether or not two simplicial complexes are homeomorphic is undecidable. Markov *fils* showed this in 1958 by reduction to the word problem for groups.

Comment: This is one of my favourite examples, but again it's not *purely* group-theoretic. Markov had to be careful to ensure that the simply-connected manifolds he constructed were homeomorphic. (These days it's easier using Freedman, but that's an even bigger topological hammer!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm still a little uncertain about this question, but I'll try to say something about the Virtual Haken conjecture (discussed above) and in the process explain why I think it's a good example.

The Virtual Haken conjecture (now Agol's theorem) can be stated as follows --

> Every hyperbolic 3-manifold has a finite-sheeted cover that contains an embedded, incompressible surface.

-- a thoroughly topological statement (though more group-theoretic statements can be given).

For me, modern (geometric) group theory enters the picture in a truly astonishing way via the following result, Wise's *Malnormal Special Quotient Theorem* (MSQT).

> Let $G$ be a hyperbolic, virtually special group, and $H$ a malnormal, quasiconvex subgroup.  Then, for all sufficiently deep finite-index subgroups $K\lhd H$, the quotient $G/\langle\langle K\rangle\rangle$ is hyperbolic and virtually special.

I won't explain the definitions here, but rather point out that this tells us that we can kill large subgroups and stay in the (very well behaved) world of hyperbolic, virtually special groups.  *Note that this is not true of manifolds.*  You can't crush an immersed surface in a hyperbolic manifold and get a new manifold.

Although the proofs of the MSQT can (and usually are) phrased in an entirely topological/geometric manner, the key point here is that they concern geometric complexes (more precisely, CAT(0) cube complexes), not manifolds.  The transition from manifolds to more general geometric complexes is surely the hallmark of modern infinite group theory.

Agol's proof, still the only proof we know, makes essential use of the MSQT.  In this sense, the Virtual Haken conjecture is truly a theorem of geometric group theory rather than topology, in the sense that we don't know how to keep the proof purely in the world of topology (ie manifolds) -- you have to pass to the world of CAT(0) cube complexes (ie group theory).